# Reading filenames with DIR in <dirent.h>

Tags: c++, macos, dirent.h

So, I'm working on a project for my C++ course. Im making music player but have some issues reading from a folder. I'm currently reading song names from a textfile, but I want to read the names from the files in a folder.
Old code:

```
std::vector<Song>tempHold;
string songNames;
string fileName = resourcePath()+"songsFile.txt";
std::ifstream dataIn;
//int wantedSongs = 16;
dataIn.open(fileName.c_str());
if(dataIn.is_open())
{
    while(getline(dataIn,songNames))
    {
        tempHold.push_back(Song(songNames,"Taylor Swift"));
        amount++;
    }

}else{
    std::cout << "error opening file";
    return tempHold;
}
```

new code that doesn't work (this is the one I need help with)

```
std::vector<Song>addSongsDir(int &amount)
{
    std::vector<Song>tempHold;
    string aLine;
    string songNames;
    string fileName = "/Users/adambjorkman/Desktop/testmusik";
    DIR * songDir;
    songDir = opendir(fileName.c_str());
    while(readdir(songDir))
    {
        tempHold.push_back(Song(songNames,""));
        std::cout << songNames;
    }
}
```

I have now made another try

```
std::vector<Song>addSongsDir(int &amount)
{
    std::vector<Song>tempHold;

    string aLine;
    string songNames;
    string fileName = "/Users/adambjorkman/Desktop/testmusik";
    DIR * songDir;
    songDir = opendir(fileName.c_str());
    struct dirent *songDirent;
    if(songDir == NULL)
    {
        throw " No such directory";
    }
    else
    {

        while((songDirent = readdir(songDir)))
        {
            songNames = songDirent->d_name;
            tempHold.push_back(Song(songDirent->d_name,""));
            std::cout << songNames;
        }
    }
    return tempHold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't return anything (missing `return tempHold;`).

Secondly you aren't using `readdir()` correctly.  It returns a `struct dirent` containing information about the file it's found.  You will need to append the filename to the directory name you pass-in, in order to create the fullpath.

Thirdly, you need to avoid resource leaks by calling `closedir()` on the `DIR *` object.

Lastly, you should add some error checking (`opendir()` will fail if you don't specify a directory) and it will help your development to see those error messages in logfiles or whatever.

Comment: Oh yeah, i forgot to add those to the code when i pasted it here, sorry about that. 

How do you mean by append the filename t the directory name? 
Maybe I misunderstood the return of readdir.
Error checking will be implemented now! :)

Comment: @N0IZE Well it depends if you want to hold the fullpath to any files found by `readdir()`.  It will only return the leafname, so you need to manually append that to the directory name you used with `opendir()` in order to create the fullpath.

Comment: Hmm, okay I really only need the filename+filetype, for using in my project(making a simple musicplayer with SFML(requiered). And atm im using the first code for reading the names.

Comment: @N0IZE Well that makes it slightly easier then.

Comment: Yeah, however, im still kinda lost, will post my try later on.(my brain is so slow right now, just had exams in calculus this week :P )

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I succeeded to read from my folder. 
@trojanfoe So this is what it looks like in my console output http://gyazo.com/cfb95a19a90157ad3357922f8f6261cc

Any ideas to remove the dots+ DS_STORE in the beginning and end?

Comment: Got rid of the .DS_store by creating a folder with music on my windows computer instead. 
however now the dots remain. and seekdir, seems to not move it forward.

Comment: The normal pattern is to test what the filename is and if you don't want it, simply ignore it with `continue`.  Same goes for sub-directories or any other file.